# How to use string literal match to match multiple strings in python?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I am trying to get the index of a data frame where the rows contain exact same strings of my interest. This is my attempt:

```
import re
     findheaderindex = b[re.match(b.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str)),'start|finish|client')].index
```

I am trying to find the indices where the strings match the ones I have listed in the `re.match` function.

I was using the following code, which is working

```
findheaderindex = b[b.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('start|finish|client').any(), axis=1)].index
```

But the problem is that this gives me any rows that contain the strings, such as `Finishing`, `Starting`, or other similar words, and I don't want that to happen in my operation. So, how do I do a string literal match in python to find the indices?

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/GQGv8s/1) help?

Comment: `.str.contains(r'\b(?:start|finish|client)\b')`